# Python function keeps returning empty list [[],[],[]]

Tags: python, empty-list

This might be a bit obvious but I'm relatively new to python.

So I was trying a small block of code to print a list containing the smallest string from each of the sublist from the following data.

```
my_movies = [['How I Met Your Mother', 'Friends', 'Silicon Valley'],['Family Guy', 'South Park', 'Rick and Morty'],['Breaking Bad', 'GOT', 'The Wire', 'The Last of Us']]
```

Surprisingly I'm getting empty list as output. Can someone please help me out with this?

```
def min_length(my_movies):
    all_small_movies=[]
    minlen=2
    for movies in my_movies:
        if len(movies)<minlen:
            minlen=len(movies)
            all_small_movies=[movies]
    return all_small_movies
small_new_list=list(map(min_length,my_movies))
```

Comment: A [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/509868) is usually helpful for such problems. You may actually want to calculate the result manually and try to find the place where the program goes wrong. If you don't find the problem, please [edit] your question and show which result you want to get.

Comment: Well it's related to logic then python. From what I can see `minlen=sys.maxsize` should solve this issue.

Comment: Pranjal's solution should fix the issue. But to be more Pythonic you can just use `return min(my_movies, key=lambda s : len(s))`

Comment: Thanks @Pranjal for the detiled explanation. I underestood the logical mistake made here `minlen=2`

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat or just `return min(my_movies, key=len)`. In fact, the whole code can be done as a one-liner, `small_new_list=[min(movies, key=len) for movies in my_movies]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned, it's an issue with initialization value of minlen

here is the updated code

```
import sys

my_movies = [['How I Met Your Mother', 'Friends', 'Silicon Valley'],['Family Guy', 'South Park', 'Rick and Morty'],['Breaking Bad', 'GOT', 'The Wire', 'The Last of Us']]

def min_length(my_movies):
    all_small_movies=[]
    minlen=minlen=sys.maxsize
    for movies in my_movies:
        if len(movies)<minlen:
            minlen=len(movies)
            all_small_movies=[movies]
    return all_small_movies
small_new_list=list(map(min_length,my_movies))

print(small_new_list)
```

Here is the output

```
[['Friends'], ['Family Guy'], ['GOT']]
```

You can obviously see that you're appending a list into list. You can modify it's behavior according to your requirement.

It also takes first smallest string, if there are multiple smallest string of same size it will ignore other. You can decide what you want to do and update this accordingly.

Also try to use debugger before posting issues, it will be great learning for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a line that says

```
if len(movies)<minlen:
```

That never allows your code to execute. You broke your `movies` into a list of lists, and use

```
for movies in my_movies:
```

This line iterates through the embedded lists, all of which are longer than length 2, meaning that `len(movies)` is never less than `minlen` and `all_small_movies` remains empty.